# Why do zip files get corrupted on USB Drives?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, zip, archiving

Why do older USB drives corrupt zip files? The file size appears the same, but the CRC check fails.

Comment: the old usb drives isn't healthy, broken, most likely

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your USB drive is toast. It probably has bad blocks in the filesystem somehow (hardware failure? Who knows). You only particularly notice it with zip files because they have a CRC to test their own integrity. Throw the flash drive away.